# Finding and breaking links external source does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an XLSX workbook running on MS Excel 1908 that indicates having `links to external sources` after copying a sheet from another document.

When opening the document Excel provides the popup:

`This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe Update / Don't Update`

When I click Update: I get a window  that states

```
We can't update some of the links in your workbook right now Continue / Edit Links...
```

When I select `Edit links...` I get the Edit links Window in which the reference is shown to the linked document.

I attempted the following:

`'Break Link'` does not work

`'Change source'` does not work

A search in Excel for the string of the location (in cells, entire workbook) does not yield a result.

No `Names` are defined with this reference.

No `custom VBA` scripts exist with this reference.

Where more can this link be  located? And how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use Find and look for a [

(Example below) IF there is an external link it should inform you.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is helpful. However, the link does not seem to be in any cell, or defined name in the workbook. I'm thinking there might be a "meta" layer in the excel that still has links defined that cannot be accessed. Or is this crazy?

Answer (score 1):

My bet would have been on a defined name. Assuming you checked all these places:
[image]

Failing that, you can try

1. File > Info > Inspect Document, or
2. File > Info > Edit links to files, or
3. Try saving the document back into an older .xls format then resaving in .xlsx, or
4. Try to unhide any hidden names in VBA like so (source https://professor-excel.com/named-ranges-excel-hidden-names/). Also have a search for "VBA hidden external connections or links"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Existing connections, Queries and Connections say "0" or no connections. When I select "Edit links" I see the links, but WHERE are these located? You cannot get any information on the location of these links.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste a screenshot of the Edit links dialog box? In addition, it might be that these links or names have been deliberately hidden use VBA code (then had the code removed). See updated answer.